# How to automatically request a review from someone using GitHub actions?

Tags: github, yaml, github-actions

I would like to use a GitHub action/do some config that automatically requests a review from a team in a GitHub organization (for example `core`). I know that you can create pull request templates that automatically request a review from a certain reviewer but how do I do this without creating a template? In summary, I would like to have a team in GitHub `core` automatically requested a review for each PR opened. How do I do this?

Comment: That's what [code owners](https://docs.github.com/en/github/creating-cloning-and-archiving-repositories/about-code-owners) are for.

Comment: Is it possible to do automatically request a review from a team that doesn't have write access to the repository and just triage?

Comment: There is a role for exactly that (in GitHub Organizations): it's called "triage" (see [here](https://docs.github.com/en/github/setting-up-and-managing-organizations-and-teams/repository-permission-levels-for-an-organization#permission-levels-for-repositories-owned-by-an-organization)). You can create a team containing the people whom you want to review, then give that team "triage" role in your repository and also set the team as code owners.

Comment: Oh, no, code owners can't have only the "triage" role, it requires at least "write".

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In general, this is a good use case for the [code owners](https://docs.github.com/en/repositories/managing-your-repositorys-settings-and-features/customizing-your-repository/about-code-owners) feature: you could have a file `.github/CODEOWNERS` that looks like

```
* @yourorg/core
```

This requests a review from that team on any pull request opened.

However, this requires the team to have write permissions on the repository, and (as per comments) the intention is to not give this team write permissions.

With the team having only "triage" permissions, this could be achieved with the following workflow:

```yaml
name: Request review on PRs

on:
  pull_request:
    types:
      - opened

jobs:
  request:
    name: Request reviews on opened PRs
    runs-on: ubuntu-22.04

    steps:
      - name: Create PR review request
        env:
          GITHUB_TOKEN: ${{ secrets.GITHUB_TOKEN }}
          url: ${{ github.event.pull_request.html_url }}
        run: |
          gh pr edit "$url" --add-reviewer yourorg/core
```

This runs on each opened pull request and creates a review request from the `yourorg/core` team using the [`pr edit`](https://cli.github.com/manual/gh_pr_edit) command of the [GitHub CLI](https://cli.github.com/), which is pre-installed on the virtual environments.

Comment: In some organizations this may not work: With `permissions:'write-all'` :
error fetching organization teams: Resource not accessible by integration

Comment: @DrewryPope That probably depends on the [default permissions of the `GITHUB_TOKEN`](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/security-guides/automatic-token-authentication#permissions-for-the-github_token), though I'm not sure which scope would apply to this specific error.

Comment: Having bumped into this myself just now, it looks like the only solution is to use a personal access token with, probably, the `repo` and `read:org` scopes, at least.