# How can I solve the problem with CODEOWNERS in Github

Tags: github

I habe a problem with Github Codeowners.

I created CODEOWNERS file in my root repo. and in this file I have defined as follows

```
*       @CodeownerTeam


/tests/ @testTeam
```

and the structure of repo is very easy.

```
tests
   test.java
features
  feature.java
web
```

What I expected is that if I make some change in test.java, after creating pull request, It should  be seen reviewer in github the testTeam.

but it was not working...
any solutions?

Comment: It would be a lot easier to read this if you removed all the irrelevant (and incorrect) comments and left your actual rules. You also have "@testTeam2" in your file and "testTeam" in your description, and don't really describe what "it was not working" means.

Comment: Hi, I have edited my question

Comment: Does testTeam belong to an org? If yes then it should be @org/testTeam.

See if this can help https://docs.github.com/en/repositories/managing-your-repositorys-settings-and-features/customizing-your-repository/about-code-owners and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66557514/how-to-automatically-request-a-review-from-someone-using-github-actions