# When a Pull Request is opened in github how can I automatically request a minimum number of approvers?

Tags: github, github-actions

On opening a pull request in github, I automatically want to request that 2 approvers are required for this specific PR. Is this possible?

Comment: Could make a team of codeowners, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66557514/how-to-automatically-request-a-review-from-someone-using-github-actions

Comment: There is also an action to use on a Github workflow to [assign reviewers](https://github.com/marketplace/actions/github-action-for-assignee-to-reviewer) automatically.